# Draw text on the top left corner of canvas

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

how do I write some text (with `canvas.drawText`?) ont the middle of the screen and on the left top corner?
thank you (-:

Answer (score 25):

I don't know why the above answer is marked with V when it's simply not correct. Drawing text at (0,0) will draw it off screen since, for some reason, the text is drawn from the bottom up (whereas everything else seem to be drawn from up to bottom).

If you want the top left corner:

```
paint = new Paint();
paint.setColor(Color.RED);
int fontSize = 20;
paint.setTextSize(fontSize);
Typeface tf = Typeface.create("FONT_NAME", Typeface.BOLD);
paint.setTypeface(tf);
paint.setTextAlign(Align.LEFT);
canvas.drawText("your_text", 0, (0+paint.getTextSize()), paint);
```

Comment: Awesome man! I was going mad here! Thanks for taking the time to answer this question with the correct answer! Please upvote this answer!

Comment: Yes, it's important to know that canvas.drawText() renders from bottom, left (assuming align value is set to left) and not the usual top, left.

Comment: @param y The y-coordinate of the baseline of the text being drawn

Answer (score 1):

using the ctx.textBaseline='top' it sets the position to the top then use ctx.textAlign='start' to position it to the left.
example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>My Webpage</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
    </head>

    <body>
        <canvas id="gameCanvas"></canvas>
        <script>
        let canvas = document.getElementById('gameCanvas');
        let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        canvas.height=window.innerHeight;
        canvas.width=window.innerWidth;
        ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(0,0,0)';
        ctx.font = "15px Arial";
        ctx.textAlign='start';
        ctx.textBaseline='top';
        ctx.fillText("Hello World", 0, 0);
        </script>  
     </body>
</html>
```